# Removing $4K_3s$ from $K_6$ leaves no other $K_3$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Prove or disprove: Removing $4$ distinct $K_3$s from $K_6$ leaves no other $K_3$.

I tried this and I believe it is true and to prove it I noted that when we remove $4K_3$s we are left with $3$ edges which are not incident to the same vertices. I don't know how to say this more precisely.. I think that each of the vertices is involved in $2K_3$s and at the end they have degree $1$. I just need to formulate this nicely. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why all vertices must have degree $1$ at the end is a parity argument.

At the beginning, all vertices have degree $5$, which is odd. Every time you take out a $K_3$, you decrease the degrees of three vertices by $2$, so all degrees remain odd. So after you've taken out four $K_3$'s, the degrees of the vertices are $6$ odd numbers that sum up to $6$ (because there are $3$ edges remaining). This can only happen by taking $1+1+1+1+1+1 = 6$, so all degrees are $1$ at the end.

(Similarly, we can show that in any graph that can be decomposed into $K_3$'s, all vertex degrees must be even. So it might be possible with $K_5$ and $K_7$ (turns out that it is possible for $K_7$, but not for $K_5$) but definitely isn't possible for $K_6$.)

Comment: Oh, nice point! I will keep that in mind!

Comment: Isn't the problem badly stated? Certainly, if you remove $4$ **edge-disjoint** $K_3$'s from $K_6,$ you will not be left with a $K_3.$ But $4$ "distinct" $K_3$'s could all be contained in a $K_4.$

Comment: @bof "Removing" $K_3$'s seemed to me to imply that they're edge-disjoint: after all, once you remove a $K_3$, those edges are gone, and you can't remove them again. (Plus, as usual, context helps, which in this case includes the asker's work removing $K_3$'s which are clearly edge-disjoint.)

Comment: I was pretty sure what the OP *meant* but I still think the problem was badly stated; I would have used "edge-disjoint" instead of "distinct". For one thing, the four $K_3$'s could all be removed simultaneously. For another, why even bother to say "distinct", you can't remove the same triangle twice.